# How use pipe in reactive form field?

Tags: javascript, angular

I use reactive form in angular6. form fields contains decimal values, but i need transform these decimal values to integer values.

Important: accuracy should not be lost. ONLY IN TEMPLATE user should be seen integer values. But in component(aka controller) values should be decimals.

[LIVE DEMO here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2o9ew)

My try:

template:

```
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <input formControlName="{{name1 | testPipe}}">
  <input formControlName="{{name2 | testPipe}}">
  <input formControlName="{{name3 | testPipe}}">
</form>
```

component(aka controller):

```
  fg: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      name1: this.fb.control(1.3),
      name2: this.fb.control(33.34),
      name3: this.fb.control(3.5),
    })
  }
```

pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'testPipe'
})
export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): any {
    return Math.round(+value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a directive, not a pipe. In the directive you listen onBlur and onFocus events to store the value and show the rounded value. Some like

```
@Directive({ selector: "[testPipe]" })
export class TestPipe  implements OnInit {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  private value: any;  //<--here you store the "real value"
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus() {
    this.el.value = this.value; // on focus return the value stored
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {     //in blur
    this.value = value;  //store the real value
    this.el.value = '' + Math.round(+value); //change the value you show
  }
  ngOnInit()  //At init
  {
    this.value = this.el.value; 
    this.el.value = '' + Math.round(+this.value);

  }
```

And you use like

```
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <input formControlName="name1" testPipe >
  <input formControlName="name2" testPipe>
  <input formControlName="name3" testPipe>
</form>
{{fg?.value |json}}
```

You can see [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkv55q?file=src/app/app.component.html)

NOTE: It's very strange the way you want to manage the pipes and create the formGroup, see the code

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is doing is piping the form control *name*, not the value.

You might wanna import your pipe in the template and transform the value there within the form builder. Depending on what your pipe does, you might need to go with an actual FormControl in the template there and template piping, and not FormControlName.